# XSLT Split XML file using Skip and Take like approach

Tags: xml, xslt

Our orders come in as XML, one of our customers is now sending in huge orders for christmas (25mb xml files), this pretty much grinds our system to a halt! I need to find a decent way to split this file into several files of x size or y number of orders. I can do this with a simple console app but I am wondering if I it can be done with XSLT?

I want to select elements say 2 at a time for this example. Is there a kind of skip and take style method for this?

Example order file:

```
<order>
    <customerName>Customer 1</customerName>
    <orderID>001</orderID>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>001</itemID>
        <quantity>12</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>002</itemID>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>003</itemID>
        <quantity>120</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>004</itemID>
        <quantity>1223</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>005</itemID>
        <quantity>22</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>006</itemID>
        <quantity>78</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
```

I want to split it into XML documents containing 2 orderItems each:

File 1:

```
<order>
    <customerName>Customer 1</customerName>
    <orderID>001</orderID>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>001</itemID>
        <quantity>12</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>002</itemID>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
```

File 2:

```
<order>
    <customerName>Customer 1</customerName>
    <orderID>001</orderID>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>003</itemID>
        <quantity>120</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>004</itemID>
        <quantity>1223</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
```

File 3:

```
<order>
    <customerName>Customer 1</customerName>
    <orderID>001</orderID>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>005</itemID>
        <quantity>22</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>006</itemID>
        <quantity>78</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
```

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime? With XSLT 2.0 you can create multiple result files with one stylesheet, using `xsl:result-document`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you are limited to XSLT 1.0.

In this case you can use the **[MVP-XML project and its EXSLT.NET component](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EXSLT.NET&referringTitle=Home)**.

More specifically, you will use the **[`<exsl:document>`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** extension element to generate multiple output from the same transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- split file up into order elements -->
<xsl:template match="orderItem[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <order>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".|following-sibling::orderItem[not(position() > 1)]"/>
    </order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderItem"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your source XML you get this output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
<customerName>Customer 1</customerName>
<orderID>001</orderID>
<order>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>001</itemID>
        <quantity>12</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>002</itemID>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
<order>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>003</itemID>
        <quantity>120</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>004</itemID>
        <quantity>1223</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
<order>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>005</itemID>
        <quantity>22</quantity>
    </orderItem>
    <orderItem>
        <itemID>006</itemID>
        <quantity>78</quantity>
    </orderItem>
</order>
</order>
```

The question is if you system supports this split. The one I am working with supports it and adds `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` automatically so the split orders would be seperate XMLs and those get processed one by one.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for your response but no our system won't support that. XML files get added to MSMQ and processed in turn. I need the split to queue 10 small files instead of 1 large one. Thanks

Comment: Hello, Please have a look at Dimitre's answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160014/split-xml-into-multiple-html-files-using-xslt/12160710#12160710 I hope that helps. Best regards, Peter